# Как разрешить пользователю выбрать изображение ТАП-ом по ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

Пустое новое приложение. Разместил ImageView, в который планируется размещение самим пользователем изображения из галереи.
Все инструкции которые прочитал предлагают создать кнопку для вызова диалога с иконкой галереи и камеры.

Но я хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь просто коснулся фрейма ImageView и открылась галерея, а после выбора нужного изображения, оно сохранилось в ImageView.
То есть **без создания дополнительной кнопки**.
По совету Andrew привожу MainActivity.java в такое состояние:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View imgView = findViewById(R.id.b1_photo);

        imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v(TAG, " click");
            }
        });

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Остальные вставки из совета вызывают красный забор ошибок.

Comment: @Rus Обьясните пожалуйста, а чего вы пытаетесь добится последними правками? Ведь вы приняли данный вам ответ.

Comment: @Rus Принятый ответ означает, что он помог вам с решением и вы его проверили. Ознакомтесь пожалуйста с обсуждением вашего [вопроса на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10066/217579).

Comment: Сорри если я что-то нарушил  - пока не совсем разобрался с правилами и функциональностью этого места.

Comment: Коллеги, просьба воздержаться от откатов, чтобы не стартовать войну правок.

Comment: вам нужно `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);` вставить в слушатель нажатий кнопки на место `Log.v(TAG, " click");`

Comment: `onActivityResult` - эту функцию укажите за пределами функции `onCreate` но в пределах класса `MainActivity `, просто скопируйте и вставьте после функции `onCreate()`

Comment: `View imgView = findViewById(R.id.b1_photo);` тут исправьте с `View` на `ImageView`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно просто сделать обработчик нажатий по `ImageView` и все, чтобы не заморачиваться. Для этого добавьте в XML виджета:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

потому, что картинки вообще не кликабельные. Далee, в активности делаете функцию:

```
imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Log.v(TAG, " click");         
   }        
});
```

либо второй вариант:

```
imgView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      // X = event.getX()
      // Y = event.getY()
      return false;
   }            
});
```

и дальше уже при клике переходите в галерею:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Отлавливаете путь картинки:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmapImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Дальше уже сетите в `imageview` выбранную картинку.

Comment: я вам под вашим вопросом написал комментарии, ознакомьтесь на досуге!!!

Comment: я точно следую вашим указаниям. Дело важное - вы потратили свое время чтобы поделиться знаниями, и я к этому отношусь с большим уважением - досуг это не про меня.